# Secure communication between my own applications

Tags: android, security, broadcastreceiver, communication

I want to communicate to apps. The Sender and the Receiver.
The sender uses this simple code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("my.app.intent.MyMessageHere");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The Receiver gets it without any problem. But the question is:
Is the Receiver app able to know who sent the broadcast? I mean, can I check that my Sender ws the one that sent the message?
Of course, all this is for security reasons.
I don't want other app to send stuff to my Receiver.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this was asking for security you can use `sendBroadcast(intent, receiverPermission)` and ***don't use implicit Intent***.

Use Explicit Intent, So that only one application can listen your broadcasted data. like

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("my.app.intent.MyMessageHere");
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename of receiver app","receiverclassname.java"));
```

And send as `sendBroadcast(intent)`.

If you want more security you can Introduce custom permission. And then you need that permission into both apps, that will ensure that your communication is more secure.

---

***How to add custom permission***

```
<permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" android:label="my_permission" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" />
```

add above code into both apps manifest. Read more about [android:protectionLevel="signature"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

So you have to sign your both app with same certificate. So if another app having the same permission can't listen your broadcast until signed by your certificate.

Now you have to add `android:permission="com.testpackage.mypermission"` into the receiver in manifest of receiver app. Thats it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you give me more info about those "custom permissions". What do I have to do?

Comment: @Ton See my updated answer. I am leaving now. If you have an issue I will reply back to you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You can pass sender information through Intent putExtra and Receiver can reteive this value using getIntent and getExtra.This way receiver will come to know that your app has send the broadcast.

Comment: Well, but if there is another app listening then it can be a problem. That other app will be able to catch that information and then send it by itself. Do you know what I mean? I really want to be sure that my app was the one that sent the message. So no other apps can emulate my sender.